# Parsing JSON in Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I need to extract the following json:

```
{"PhysicalDisks":[{"Status":"SMART Passed","Name":"/dev/sda"}]}
{"PhysicalDisks":[{"Status":"SMART Passed","Name":"/dev/sda"},{"Status":"SMART Passed","Name":"/dev/sdb"}]}
{"PhysicalDisks":[{"Status":"SMART Passed","Name":"/dev/sda"},{"Status":"SMART Passed","Name":"/dev/sdb"}]}
{"PhysicalDisks":[{"Name":"disk0","Status":"Passed"},{"Name":"disk1","Status":"Passed"}]}
{"PhysicalDisks":[{"Name":"disk0","Status":"Failed"},{"Name":"disk1","Status":"not supported"}]}
{"PhysicalDisks":[{"Name":"disk0","Status":"Passed"}]}

Name: raw_results, dtype: object
```

Into separate columns. I don't know how many disks per result there might be in future. What would be the best way here?

I tried the following:

```
d = raw_res['raw_results'].map(json.loads).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('raw_results.')
```

Gives me:

[image]

Example output might be something like 
[image]

Better way would be to add each disk check as an additional row into dataframe with the same checkid as the row it was extracted from. So for 3 disks in results it will generate 3 rows 1 per disk

## **UPDATE**

This code

```
# This works
dfs = []
def json_to_df(row, json_col):
    json_df = pd.read_json(row[json_col])
    dfs.append(json_df.assign(**row.drop(json_col)))

df['raw_results'].replace("{}", pd.np.nan, inplace=True)
df = df.dropna()
df.apply(json_to_df, axis=1, json_col='raw_results')
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.head()
```

Adds an extra row for each disk (sda, sdb etc.)
[image]

So now I would need to split this column into 2: Status and Name.

Comment: What would the expected output look like?

Comment: something like 
| sda_passed | sdb_passed | ...
[br]
| 1                  | NaN              |

Comment: sda_passed = for one "PhysicalDisks"  length of the status which are passed ? what are sdb_passed and sdc_passed ?

Comment: Please post desired results in body of question and not comments. A few rows are helpful. BTW, that is not valid JSON. But each line is valid JSON just not together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 = df["PhysicalDisks"].apply(pd.Series)
df_final = pd.concat([df, df1], axis = 1).drop('PhysicalDisks', axis = 1)
df_final.head()
```

[image]